# Information Right Management : Unhandled exception initializing IRM

Tags: sharepoint-server, irm

Here is our scenario :

We have a SharePoint 2016 Three Tier Farm composed with:

- 1 WFE
- 1 APP
- 1 SQL Server
- *configured in **Domain A***

We have two RMS servers

- **RMSSRV.DOMAIN-A.COM**
- **RMSSRV.DOMAIN-B.COM**
- *managed with trust between them*
- SharePoint Build Version is 16.0.4756.1000 (October 2018 CU)
- OS In all servers is Windows Server 2016, SQL Server Version 2016 SP1

When trying to link SharePoint 2016 with RMS we get the famous error:

> The required Active Directory Rights Management Service Client
>   (MSIPC.DLL) is present but could not be configured properly. IRM will
>   not work until the client is configured properly.

We gave correct permissions (Even Full Control) to the web service files : **ServerCertification.asmx**, **Certification.asmx**, **Licensing.asmx** in the two RMS Servers for the SharePoint Farm Account, SharePoint Installation Account, SharePoint Service Apps Account and the Three SharePoint Server Farm Computers.

*We Downloaded RMS Analyzer Tool and the Diagnostic was SUCCESSFUL.*

When digging in ULS Logs when trying to link in Central Administration we get the following informations :

```
   2/31/2018 21:35:10.64  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   Information Rights Management   a3vg6   Medium     Load MSIPC.DLL - version:[1.0.3356.1108],
 location:[C:\Program Files\Active Directory Rights Management Services Client 2.1\\msipc.dll].    7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:10.65  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   Information Rights Management   ayh6i   Medium     OauthRmsoEnabled checked status of
 flight. Status: 'Disabled'   7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:10.65  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   Information Rights Management   a4hyw   Medium     OAuth for RMSO is turned OFF by flighting.  7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:10.65  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   Information Rights Management   a3vg6   Medium     Load MSIPC.DLL - version:[1.0.3356.1108],
 location:[C:\Program Files\Active Directory Rights Management Services Client 2.1\\msipc.dll].    7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:11.00  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   General   837l    Exception   An unhandled exception occured. Watson will be invoked.
 StackTrace: at onetnative.dll: (sig=ecaed601-b36b-4e35-afcc-e259d5b7a450|2|onetnative.pdb, offset=3712D) at onetnative.dll: (offset=1E332) at onetnative.dll: (offset=1E218) at onetutil.dll: (sig=26f187a2-9468-47cb-8752-ad62cb2856dc|2|onetutil.pdb, offset=A7353)
 at VCRUNTIME140.dll: (sig=d348f660-cfde-4900-a3b9-651782bc59c6|1|vcruntime140.amd64.pdb, offset=BEE0) at VCRUNTIME140.dll: (offset=229A) at VCRUNTIME140.dll: (offset=2180) at VCRUNTIME140.dll: (offset=1C7E) at VCRUNTIME140.dll: (offset=BE80) at ntdll.dll:
 (sig=87db6e61-82d3-43ab-b833-94f73bb3973e|1|ntdll.pdb, offset=AA57D) at ntdll.dll: (offset=3FD23) at ntdll.dll: (offset=A96EA) at ipcauth.dll: (sig=84b5cad7-9763-4d5c-b87d-069364a54683|1|ipcauth.pdb, offset=2E0B4) at ipcauth.... 7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:11.00* w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   General   837l    Exception   ...dll: (offset=1AA58) at msipc.dll: (sig=87ca7079-2e28-430e-97f3-fa82a2397d87|1|msipc.pdb,
 offset=A7640) at msipc.dll: (offset=A737D) at msipc.dll: (offset=5621F) at msipc.dll: (offset=47442) at msipc.dll: (offset=4E66C) at stswel.dll: (sig=57b6387c-0451-45bf-a3d9-aed6be492648|2|stswel.pdb, offset=169830) at stswel.dll: (offset=169445) at stswel.dll:
 (offset=16AF87) at stswel.dll: (offset=1664AA) at stswel.dll: (offset=167A75) at owssvr.dll: (sig=cd4583e7-7bfd-448a-a85c-bdccecea7957|2|owssvr.pdb, offset=3EA93)    7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:11.00  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   Unified Logging Service   c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 100010ff "16.0.4351.0", 605a3328 "ipcauth.dll", 01000d1c "1.0.3356.0", 5a02bfdd "wed nov 8 09:27:09 2017", MISSING, 0002e0b4 "0002e0b4", c0000005
 "c0000005", 3833376c "837l"   7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:11.05  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   General   ac97k   High     Unhandled exception initializing IRM. 0x00000000   7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6

12/31/2018 21:35:11.05  w3wp.exe (0x2FBC)     0x0868  SharePoint Foundation   Information Rights Management   5808    Information Information Rights Management (IRM): Initial
 certificate acquisition and other Rights Management Services (RMS) initialization actions were completed with result code: 0x80020009. 7082b19e-84e8-603d-892b-9b6c880ca0b6
```

I can't understand what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, please make sure you have configured RMS correctly. You can check your process as the following articles.

[Configuring Information Rights Management in SharePoint 2013.](http://sp-vinod.blogspot.com/2013/08/configuring-information-rights.html)

[Azure RMS Connector and SharePoint 2013 IRM Configuration.](http://www.kwokhau.com/2016/11/sharepoint-2013-irm-configuration.html)

And add the SharePoint site into the trusted site in IE.

Comment: RMS is correctly configured, i can encrypt the documents without SP IRM, the SharePoint site is trusted in IE, i even used a PowerShell script to bypass Central Admin but it was not configured correctly.